# Wrap WebAPI-returned JSON inside a JSON object for consumption by jQuery datatables

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, datatables

I'm using ASP.NET WebAPI Controller to output some JSON which I will consume on a web page using the [JQuery datatables plug-in](https://datatables.net).  The following controller does the outputting:

```
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<AdminNotification> ListPendingNotifications()
    {
        var db = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database;

        //Get list of notification objects to iterate over
        var notifications = db.Query<AdminNotification>("SELECT * FROM rsiAdminNotification WHERE dateTimeClosed IS NULL ORDER BY dateTime DESC");

        return notifications;
    }
```

This outputs data in the following format:

```
[ { "adminNotificationTypeId" : 11,
    "customerId" : 0,
    "dateTime" : "2014-05-15T20:16:00Z",
    "dateTimeClosed" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  },
  { "adminNotificationTypeId" : 7,
    "customerId" : 0,
    "dateTime" : "2014-05-06T11:31:00Z",
    "dateTimeClosed" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  },
  { "adminNotificationTypeId" : 7,
    "customerId" : 0,
    "dateTime" : "2014-05-06T11:31:00Z",
    "dateTimeClosed" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

However, it seems that jQuery datatables will only accept the JSON if it's wrapped in a parent JSON object.  So I need to somehow transform the controller so it outputs:

```
{
  "data": [
    { "adminNotificationTypeId" : 11,
      "customerId" : 0,
      "dateTime" : "2014-05-15T20:16:00Z",
      "dateTimeClosed" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    { "adminNotificationTypeId" : 7,
      "customerId" : 0,
      "dateTime" : "2014-05-06T11:31:00Z",
      "dateTimeClosed" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    { "adminNotificationTypeId" : 7,
      "customerId" : 0,
      "dateTime" : "2014-05-06T11:31:00Z",
      "dateTimeClosed" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Could anyone please advise how to wrap my output in a containing JSON object?

Many thanks.

*UPDATE 1:*

Having tried @SoftwareFactor's class below, here's where I'm at:

```
    public DataTableResult<AdminNotification> ListPendingNotifications()
    {
        var db = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database;

        var notifications = db.Query<AdminNotification>("SELECT * FROM rsiAdminNotification WHERE dateTimeClosed IS NULL ORDER BY dateTime DESC");

        var something = new DataTableResult<AdminNotification>();
        something.sEcho = 1;
        something.iTotalRecords = 1;
        something.iTotalDisplayRecords = 1;
        something.aaData = notifications;
        return something;
    }
```

I can't seem to get `something.aaData = notifications;` to map correctly.

*UPDATE 2*

Mapping the IEnumerable to a List like this, works:

```
        var notifications = db.Query<AdminNotification>("SELECT id FROM rsiAdminNotification WHERE dateTimeClosed IS NULL ORDER BY dateTime DESC");

        var something = new DataTableResult<AdminNotification>();
        something.sEcho = 1;
        something.iTotalRecords = 1;
        something.iTotalDisplayRecords = 1;

        IEnumerable<AdminNotification> enumerable = notifications;
        List<AdminNotification> asList = enumerable.ToList();

        something.aaData = asList;
        return something;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use DataTables in all of my projects, it's great. Here is a generic class that I have for my own purposes:

```
public class DataTableResult<T>
{
    public int sEcho { get; set; }
    public int iTotalRecords { get; set; }
    public int iTotalDisplayRecords { get; set; }
    public List<T> aaData { get; set; }
}
```

I just instantiate it, fill aaData property with results and return it from ApiController.

Comment: That looks really promising, thanks. I'm actually a bit of a .NET noob, so any advice as to how to integrate this into my Controller would be much appreciated - I'm not having much luck :(

Comment: Updated question above, using this class, but can't get values to map correctly to `aaData`.

Comment: You mean, DataTables does not recognize aaData?

Comment: No, it was getting the IEnumerable to map to a list, but I think I have it sorted now.  Datatable still isn't liking it, but I think that's a different issue.  Will update OP once I'm sure this part is solved.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using DataTables isn't quite as simple as what you've got there.  To make DataTables work you need to define your controller functions to receive and reply with the structured data that DataTables uses.  I think it helps to define two model classes to represent the request and response objects.  Your controller methods should take as input the request object and then they should return the response object.  Web-API will automatically handle the serialization to and from JSON for you.

For the structure of these two classes, as well as how to configure other properties of DataTables, see http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

The array member aaData can be declared as an `IEnumerable<String[]>`.  The rest of the members should be straight forward to declare.  Don't forget to set sEcho in the response object based on the value in the request object.  It's also wise to cast sEcho to an int in the process to avoid cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: Thanks @Derek. I don't need any of the inbound stuff - I literally just need a 'dumb' JSON output.  It's all working except it needs an outer object around on the JSON output.

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation on the page I gave a link to.  You aren't getting the right JSON output because the object you're returning doesn't match the structure that DataTables requires.

Comment: Thanks @Derek, but I think we're going around in circles.  My question is precicely that: how do I get the JSON into a format which DataTables will accept.  I think I have a solution derived from the answer by SoftwareFactor, so will update my original post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like newer versions of DataTable have made this even easier. The DataTableResult can now be

```
public class DataTableResult<T>
{
    public IList<T> data { get; set; }
}
```

Since the DataTable will accept a [list of objects now](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today as well. Assuming you have the Newtonsoft.Json package installed, you can use the following for your IHttpActionResult...

```
return Json(new {data = notifications});
```